# Converting Excel to JSON in Javascript results in weird behaviour and faulty values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, excel, sheetjs

I'm working on converting an Excel Worksheet to a JSON in Javascript. I encountered some issues that are to me very bizarre so I will try to explain this as well as I can. I import an Excel and use SheetJS to read to JSON:

```
    const data = await file.arrayBuffer()

    const workbook = XLSX.read(data)
    var firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0]

    //reading only first sheet data
    var jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName])
    console.log(jsonData)
```

However, when I print the result ("jsonData") by using
`console.log(jsonData)`, some numbers don't match the initial Excel input. Here is what a column of the Excel input looks like:
[image: Excel Example]
As you can see, there are just different numbers, also formatted as "Number". But the result of `console.log(jsonData)` for rows 4-6 (index start at 0) returns different/wrong values:
[image: example 3] 
So obviously, the numbers don't match up. What I don't understand is that it's also only these three values that are wrong. 
Now what's even more surprising to me is that if I take a specific index to get the value, (`console.log(jsonData[4]["Wert"])` for example, the number output is correct again: 
[image] 
 Using numbers from rows 4-7 to build up the sum (which should be 8797,59) also results in a number with many decimal places (8797.589999999998). It's really only these three values that exhibit this behavior. 
What I would like to find out:

1. Why are the results of these three values, when printed as a whole JSON (`console.log(jsonData)`, wrong?
2. Why does the sum of only these numbers result in high decimal places?

Comment: Well, first of all, seems like the fourth value is correct. At least the shown value and the should value both say 102.23.
Second, the key of the JSON is Wert/KWähr, but the column you show us is Wert. Do you have a Wert/KWähr column? Or where does that key come from?

Comment: Oh yes fourth value is correct! I removed KWähr since it's not English and I didn't want to cause confusion. I will edit the screenshot!